# Comparing the size of two measure and their extensions.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $\tilde{H} \subseteq P(X)$ be a semiring on $X$. Furthermore, let $\mu$ and $v$ be measures on $\tilde{A}$, where $\tilde{A}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\tilde{H}$. In addition, we require the restrictions $\mu_\tilde{H}$ and $v_\tilde{H}$ of $\mu$ and $v$ to $\tilde{H}$ to be $\sigma-$finite. Now I want to prove two things:

1.) If $\mu_\tilde{H}(B) \leq v_\tilde{H}(B) \ \ \forall B \in \tilde{H} $, then $\mu (B) \leq v (B) \ \ \forall B \in \tilde{A} .$

2.) The statement in 1.) is no longer valid if the semiring $\tilde{H}$ is replaced by a generator $\tilde{E}$ of $\tilde{A}$ which is closed under intersection, even if $X\in \tilde{E}$ and $v(X)<\infty$.

For 1.) I think it would be sufficient to show that the set 
$$ \tilde{D}:= \{ A \in \tilde{A} \ \vert \ \mu(A) \leq v(A) \} $$
is a $\sigma$-algebra, since we have $\tilde{H} \subseteq \tilde{D} \subseteq \tilde{A}$. But so far I have failed to prove this. Thanks for any idea!

Comment: Caratheodory's theorem tells you exactly how $\mu $ and $\nu $ (restricted to $\tilde {A} $) can be obtained from there restrictions to the semi ring $\tilde {H} $ (how?). This description tells you that the desired estimate holds.